# Rails duplicate multiple records at once and changing certain attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to duplicate multiple records from a table `Book`, and modify certain attributes at the same time, such as giving a new `user_id` and a new `library_id`.
I have put the following together

```
@new_data = Book.where(library_id: "xxxxxx").dup.tap { |ele| ele.assign_attributes(user_id: @new_user_id, library_id:  @new_library_id) }.save
```

But i have an error :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `assign_attributes' for #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055bed16fd5c0>)
```

Is there a way to do this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```rb
      @new_data = []
      Book.where(library_id: 'xxxxxx').each do |book|
        new_book = book.dup
        new_book.assign_attributes(user_id: @new_user_id, library_id:  @new_library_id)
        new_book.save
        @new_data << new_book
      end
```

Note: Rails convention dictates that `Books` should be singular. I've adjusted it to `Book` in this code.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, you are right, i was trying to make a one line solution, will just use your look. Thank you.